# How to write live testing app for HTML and JS and capture page load events

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm writing an in-browser Chrome app that will allow users to edit HTML and JS code and then be able to test their changes live.

My current method of doing this is to create a new window with JavaScript, create an IFrame in that window, and then inject the user's HTML or JS code into the IFrame.  The problem with this though, is that the page load events of the IFrame can't be used by the script being live-tested.  My app could manually call `testWindow.iframe.contentWindow.onload`, but that wouldn't work with the various events and methods used by the different JS libraries for their "domready"-style events.

Perhaps this is not possible, and I'll just have to send the code to the server and have the server output it.  I noticed apps like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) actually just ask what library and event you want.

Any ideas on how I can have live-testing in my app and still fire page loading events for the JS being tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) on the iframe, which you know will be supported since you are making a Chrome app. Alternatively, for absolutely certain cross-browser compatibility (or some other reason) you could also send the script to your server (using Ajax) to be stored in a database, then linked to in the new window.

Comment: Thanks, that should work.  How do I know when the injected code is finished loading though?

Comment: I don't believe there is any good way to do that, especially since load events do not bubble and you cannot control the order in which events fire. Why do you need to know when the code finishes loading? There could be a better way to do it.

Comment: After it loads, I replace the urls of all script, link, and img elements with relative src's to that of files within the app.

For example, if the user had a <script> pointing to /test.js, I would replace that src with the url of /test.js within the app's filesystem, if it existed.

Comment: Before `dispatchEvent`, use `addEventListener` to add a (non-capturing) load handler to the window object in the `<iframe>` (before it loads, of course) that replaces the URLs on the page. That way, the user's load event won't be able to use things before they're changed, either.

Comment: Thanks.  The thing that appears to be working for me is attaching the "load" event listener which will replace the relative URLs to the iframe, using `frame.contentDocument.write` to write the user's code, then calling `frame.contentDocument.close`, which fires the load event.  

The problem with this appears to be that `document.write`'s will not work for users after I call `document.close()`, but that's a limitation I'll have to deal with and just warn users about I suppose, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Just heard a lightening talk on http://vowsjs.org/ this evening. Haven't used it yet but I plan to explore this for testing web apps.